# Динамический список в QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

Доброго времени суток.

Есть QListWidget, необходимо из базы данных в него добавлять список компаний. В будущем, в программе используются ID компаний, и необходимо чтобы при нажатии на конкретный QListWidgetItem ID выбранной компании уже было известно. Как можно реализовать? Так как решения я не нашел, я сделал смешной костыль :

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM clients");
QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
while(query.next()){
    companyName = query.value(rec.indexOf("companyName")).toString();
    ui->listWidget->addItem(companyName);
    ID = query.value(rec.indexOf("id")).toString();
    ui->listWidget->addItem(ID);
    ui->listWidget->item(ui->listWidget->count()-1)->setHidden(true);
}
```

То есть я добавляю два элемента в ListWidget, сначала сам элемент, потом его ID, Item с ID я ставлю ->setHidden(True), и в последующей программе нахожу айди выбранной компании посредством инкремента CurrentRow(). Но с увеличением числа компаний(тестировал на 5.000), скорость оставляет желать лучшего. Подскажите более быстрое, адекватное решение) Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У [QListWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html) есть метод [void QListWidgetItem::setData(int role, const QVariant &value)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#setData), можно в него положить данные от `Qt::UserRole`, `Qt::UserRole + 1`, и т.д.

Чтобы данные получить используйте [QVariant QListWidgetItem::data(int role) const](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#data)